# SQL - how to calculate standard deviation (stddev) of x/y?

Tags: mysql, sql

Example: Calculating click-through rate (CTR)

```
CAST(SUM(num_clicks) as DOUBLE) / CAST(SUM(num_impression) as DOUBLE) as CTR
```

How can I calculate standard deviation of CTR? stddev(CTR) won't work because it would be a nested aggragated function... Also, I can't calculate CTR first then run stddev on it.

Comment: Why can't you calculate CTR first and then run `STDDEV` on it? Put the CTR calculation in a subquery, and do `STDDEV` in the outer query.

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate CTR first and then run `STDDEV_POP` on it by using a subquery.

```
SELECT STDDEV_POP(ctr) AS ctr_stddev
FROM (
    SELECT CAST(SUM(num_clicks) as DOUBLE) / CAST(SUM(num_impression) as DOUBLE) AS ctr
    FROM yourTable
    WHERE ...
    GROUP BY ad_id) AS temp
```

Comment: Cool! Why STDDEV_POP instead of STDDEV_SAMP?

Comment: I wasn't really sure which one would be right, I just picked one of them.